# Javascript SSE message notifications in reverse order

Tags: javascript, server-sent-events

I have a message notification section on my html page that receives notifications.  How could I modify this code to have new modifications inserted in reverse order?

```js
var ul = document.getElementById("out");
var eventSource = new EventSource("/stream_game_channel");
eventSource.onmessage = function(e) {
  ul.innerHTML += e.data + '<br>';
};
```

```html
<ul id="out" cols="85" rows="14"></ul>
<br>
<br>
```

Comment: ```ul.innerHTML = e.data + '<br>' + ul.innerHTML;```